# Matching regex in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to match the parameters of a bash script with a regex

```
mykill.bash [-l] [-s SIGNO] pattern1 pattern2
```

I'm using this expression:

```
regex = ^(-l)?(\s-s\s[0-9]+)?(\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+){1,2}$ <br>
if [[ $@ =~ $regex ]]; then echo 'cool'
```

for example `./mykill.bash -l -s 33 abc gives $@='-l -s 33 abc'` which passes the debuggex.com tests (see image
but it doesn't work in my script

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: ^(-l)?(\s-s **\d** [0-9]+)?(\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+){1,2}$

Comment: Note that (once you fix the unsupported `\s` and other bugs) your code won't match either `./mykill.bash -s 33 abc`.

Answer (score 4):

You have bash problems, not a regex problem.

When assigning variables in bash: no space around the `=` please.
Then if you want to preserve backslashes  and whitespace in the regex, use single quotes around it, otherwise bash eats them for breakfast. You don't need to quote cool. And close the `if` with a `fi`.

```
regex='^(-l)?(\s-s\s[0-9]+)?(\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+){1,2}$ <br>'
if [[ $@ =~ $regex ]]; then echo cool; fi
```

Or use the simpler form of the conditional:

```
[[ $@ =~ $regex ]] && echo cool
```

Answer (score 3):

Some versions of bash does not catch `\s` the way we are used to in other languages/flavors.
One version it does not catch `\s` is on my MacBook Air with `GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release-(x86_64-apple-darwin12)`.

And you should not have spaces around `=` when assigning a value to a variable.

As [Ken-Y-N](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1270789/ken-y-n) said in the comments to your post, your pattern has some problems as well, I fixed it in my code below.

This should do it if `\s` is the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
re='^(-l\ )?(-s\ [0-9]+\ )?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\ [a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$'
if [[ $@ =~ $re ]]; then
    echo 'cool'
fi
```

There's no need to escape the spaces like i did, but I find it easier to read this way.

Comment: @SzG Really? Not in my version `GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release-(x86_64-apple-darwin12)`.

Comment: Yes. I use bash 4.x. As far as I remember bash regex matching is only available in the 4.x series. But I may be wrong. But it definitely works.

Comment: @SzG So, if you substitute `\ ` in my code above with `\s` it works for you? It does not work in my bash like that, I need to actually press space to match it.

Comment: `regex='\s' && [[ "foo bar" =~ $regex ]] && echo cool` is cool. `regex='\s' && [[ "foobar" =~ $regex ]] && echo cool` is not cool.

Comment: @SzG Not cool here. I will update answer to reflect this new (for me) information.

Comment: On my system `[[` is a bash builtin. It may be a separate command on yours. You can find out by typing `type [[`.

Answer (score 0):

As per your input, this will match

```
if [[ $@ =~ -l\ -s\ [0-9]+\ [a-zA-Z]+ ]]
then 
      echo 'cool'
else
      echo 'check again' 
fi
```